# Multisim producing very low comparator output voltage

Tags: comparator, multisim

In the images below I have the same schematic in multisim, one snapshot for each state of the comparator. I've got the VCC pin connected to 12VDC and the ground and VEE pins to ground. There is a distinct difference between the two states, but 15.8 mV for a "high" doesn't seem right. Shouldn't it be VCC? What am I missing?

Note: I just realized that one of the voltage labels is over the pin, that's pin 8 that's covered.

[image]

Comment: Man, you're prolific :p And ... no? I don't know what that is.

Comment: Quick googling says they can be push-pull or open drain ... datasheet says open drain. What does that mean?

Comment: http://www.ti.com/product/lm311-n There's the datasheet.

Comment: Aaaaand http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparator#Output_type. So I need a pull up resistor ... whatever that means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LM311 has an open-collector output; when the output is high it's actually high-impedance. If you want a high voltage then you'll need to use a pullup on the output.

Comment: Well, that's obviously my issue. Thanks for the bonk on the noggin' I guess I need to go do some more learning. And probably source a different op amp, I need the output to push some current and I don't think an open drain can?

Comment: To clarify ... basically with the open collector, there's high impedance on the output when the + is higher than the - input, so the pull up resistor is connected effectively to an open providing a signal of VCC, then when the - is greater than the +, it shorts to ground so it's down to VEE?

That would also mean that when it's at a logic high, there's (virtually)no current through the output, it's just a reference, right?

Comment: That's accurate for the most part. The output won't be exactly Vcc or Vee due to impedances, but they should easily meet CMOS input thresholds.

Comment: So ... if I put a pull-up and pull-down each connected to the output, I could create a voltage divider, and if I put my relay (that's what this is for) in series with the pull-down, I should be able to actuate it, right? (that would be where R3 is in the schematic)

Comment: Putting both a pullup and a pulldown will just drain power needlessly. Use a transistor if you need to switch a load.

Comment: There's a PMOSFET on the input (the one you helped me with before) But I suppose it's not good to start bad habits. Thanks again!

Comment: Also, doesn't it drain power when it's "off" since the collector connects to ground at that point? something on the order of a few mA?

Comment: Depends on the value of the pullup.

Comment: OK. So say I'm connecting this to the gate of an N MOSFET, the MOSFET needs a discharge to ground from the gate, which would be the voltage divider I'd mentioned before which is undesirable, so I'd want two large resistances to minimize that current on each, and I'd choose values that would correctly bias the gate. Does that sound right?